# How to call and print nodeType name instead of just the number (e.g.: "ELEMENT_NODE")?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get a node and identify its node type )(e.g.: 1, 2, 3, etc..)  and the node type name (e.g.: ELEMENT_NODE, TEXT_NODE, etc...) so that it shows in the console as a sentence:

> Hi, I am "[object HTMLBodyElement]". 
>     They say I am a "1", 
>     a Node Type known as "ELEMENT_NODE". 
>     I come in the shape of a "BODY"

Ok, I found a way of listing the node type and their names with this:

```
for(let key in Node){
    console.log(key, ' = '+Node[key]);
};
```

But I am too damn inexperienced to mix this code with the code below:

```
const bodyIs = document.body;

console.log(`Hi, I am ${bodyIs}. 
    They say I am a "${bodyIs.nodeType}", 
    a Node Type known as "${bodyIs.nodeKey}". 
    I come in the shape of a "${bodyIs.nodeName}."`);
```

For sure there is no such a thing as a ".nodeKey", so of course I am getting this:

> Hi, I am "object HTMLBodyElement]". They say I am a "1", a Node Type
>   known as "undefined". I come in the shape of a "BODY."

What could I do so that instead of getting "undefined" I get "ELEMENT_NODE"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to manually create a lookup table:

```js
     const nodeTypeName = {
       1: "ELEMENT_NODE",
       2: "ATTRIBUTE_NODE",
       3: "TEXT_NODE",
       4: "CDATA_SECTION_NODE",
       //...
     };

     console.log(nodeTypeName[ document.body.nodeType ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the list of keys of any object by using Object.keys. As Node is an object, just use its list of keys and access the key name with the value of nodeType.

```js
let bodyIs = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
console.log(bodyIs, Object.keys(Node)[bodyIs.nodeType])
```

```html
<html>
<head />
<body />
</html>
```